# Theme dependent colors of selected widgets

Tags: android-layout, android, android-theme

I'm pretty sure that this question already has been answered somewhere. It just seems too common. But I can't find the answer. I can't also figure out the solution.

Here's the problem:

I want one of my TableRow's to have different background color. It's simple, I just need to add

```
android:background="#123456"
```

In TableRow's XML Declaration. But, I also want my application to have two themes. In the other theme, the TableRow should have different background color. I just can't find a way to define a color value inside a theme and use it. I would like to type something like this:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="@style/Theme.Light">
   <color "my_cool_color">#123456</color>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyApp.Dark" parent="@style/Theme.Dark">
   <color "my_cool_color">#654321</color>
</style>
```

And, in TableRow's declaration:

```
android:background="@color/my_cool_color"
```

So, when I change the theme, the color of that one TableRow's background also changes. I've tried in many ways for many hours and didn't succeed... One thing I didn't try, was creating my own widget basing on TableRow and declaring a separate style for it - I think this should work, but it's just too heavy solution for so simple problem.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can do this using attributes. First define your attribute in `attrs.xml` (this file goes under the 'values' folder):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="myCoolColor" format="color" />
</resources>
```

Then in your `styles.xml`, define `myCoolColor` for each theme:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="@style/Theme.Light">
   <item name="myCoolColor">#123456</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyApp.Dark" parent="@style/Theme.Dark">
   <item name="myCoolColor">#654321</item>
</style>
```

Now, specify `myCoolColor` as the background of your view:

```
android:background="?myCoolColor"
```

You can go further and use a reference to a color so you can keep your colors defined in one place. Change the attribute to include a reference (note that we can use a color OR a reference):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="myCoolColor" format="color|reference" />
</resources>
```

Change your `styles.xml` to reference a color for each theme:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="@style/Theme.Light">
   <item name="myCoolColor">@color/blue</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyApp.Dark" parent="@style/Theme.Dark">
   <item name="myCoolColor">@color/green</item>
</style>
```

Finally define the colors in your `colors.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
    <color name="green">#00FF00</color>
</resources>
```

That's it!

Comment: Thanks! I found something about attr.xml, but couldn't find a suitable example. On the contrary, your answer couldn't be more complete!

Comment: I found your answer very useful, and solved my problem also. +1. But I still have one problem, I want to use the defined colors in code. How can I do that, how to use the colors from attrs in code (not xml)?

Comment: Yes, but if I use the dark theme I want the color to be blue, and for the other green. But how can I get the right color in code?

Comment: Ok, I found a solution.  int[] attrs = new int[] { R.attr.myCoolColor};
   TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs); 
   int appColor = ta.getColor(0, 0);
   ta.recycle();  Hope this helps for someone that has same problem.

Comment: If you want to use that color attribute now, use `android:background="?attr/myCoolColor"`.