# Android themes trouble implementing the simplest: custom per theme color

Tags: android, android-layout, themes, android-theme

I'm a beginner in Android development and, although coding makes perfect sence, android themes IMHO don't

I have trouble implementing this simple task:

I have (for example) a color named "blah"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="blah">#F0F0F0</color>
<resources>
```

which is used everywhere in XML layouts or code and by different view complonents as "@color/blah"

I would simply like to make this **color value change per-theme**

So when i use MyTheme1, blah should be #F0F0F0 and when i use MyTheme2 blah should be #00FF00

I've been reading about themes and still cant find out how to implement this simple task, since my app does not require special styles and so on, just per-theme colors.

Thanx in advance

**UPDATE:**

After the link provided by Mohamed_AbdAllah, i successfully managed to create some
custom colors by defining them in attrs.xml and styles.xml:

**attrs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="color_item_title" format="color|reference" />
</resources>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppBaseThemeDark" parent="android:Theme.Black">
<item name="color_item_title">@color/White</item>                      
</style>
```

**But now a much more serious problem arises**

I can successfully use the color ?color_item_title in every view, 
so buttons and text actually gets that color.

But using that ?color_item_title on custom drawables or listview layouts
(THAT IS VIEWS THAT GET INFLATED DURING RUNTIME) causes a crash.

So using ?color_item_title inside a listview listitem layout crashes at
runtime with an inflater message at that line :(

**It also crashes at my drawables:** (Inflation error again)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid android:color="@color/Black" />
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:topRightRadius="8dp" />
 <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="?color_item_title" />
</shape>
```

Comment: check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630694/theme-dependent-colors-of-selected-widgets)

Comment: Although your link provided help, a more serious problem arose so i updated my post

Answer (score 3):

After searching and trying, I got the tip that there are some things you can do and **some things you cant**.

**You can**

a) Define your own attributes in attrs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="color_gallery_backround" format="color|reference" />
</resources>
```

b) Set their values in your styles.xml

```
<style name="AppBaseThemeDark" parent="android:Theme.Black">
           <item name="color_gallery_backround">@color/White</item>              
 </style>
 <style name="AppBaseThemeWhite" parent="android:Theme.Light">
           <item name="color_gallery_backround">@color/Black</item>              
 </style>
```

c) Use them in any view as ?color_gallery_backround or ?attr/color_gallery_backround
for example

```
android:background="?attr/color_gallery_backround"
```

**YOU CANT**

a) You cant access this attribute from custom drawables, as they are not valid during 
inflation

so *you cant* use ?attr/color_gallery_backround in here:

customshape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid android:color="**?attr/color_gallery_backround**" />
 <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/Black" />
</shape>
```

b) You cant access this attribute in a view that will get inflated during (for example)
a ListView as a ListItem view

So theme "support" for attributes at least up to API 10 has depth limits.

**Solutions**

As suggested, you have to create TWO separate drawables using different colors and set up attributes to reference these drawables according to theme:

attrs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="rounded_background" format="reference" />   
</resources>
```

and on each theme, setup which actual drawable to use in styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppBaseThemeDark" parent="android:Theme.Black">
           <item name="rounded_background">@drawable/round_rect_shape_dark</item>    
           </style>

    <style name="AppBaseThemeLight" parent="android:Theme.Light">
           <item name="rounded_background">@drawable/round_rect_shape_white</item>     
           </style>

</resources>
```

Now you can reference your drawable as ?rounded_background and let the theme choose it.

For inflated views inside ListView listitem layouts, you have to programmatically set colors.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can achieve what you want is to define two different colors, `blah` and `blah2` for instance, and reference it in your themes

Answer (score 0):

It works for me as John S suggested, but in the attributes definition I had to add "color|reference" instead of just "reference". So my attrs.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <attr name="rounded_background" format="color|reference" />   
    </resources>
```

Best regads!