# Android Navigation drawer Header color change

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I've got a slight problem with colors in Android. I'm writing an app with a navigation drawer, so far so good. I know how to change the themes, so now the color of the toolbar and items changes, and this works fine. However, how do I programmatically change the color of the header of the navigation drawer? I can't find anything about it on Google.

Answer (score 1):

Add navigation header at run time:

```
View view = new View(context);
view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
view.setBackgroundColor(someColor);
navigationView.addHeaderView(view);
```

Comment: Or is there any possibility to refer to a color of the selected theme?

Comment: Thnaks, but i found a very simple way. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630694/theme-dependent-colors-of-selected-widgets